# how to loop array of functions and execute one at a time onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

```
var index=0;

function canvasp() { 

    var array_of_functions = [canvaspoint,canvaspoint1];
    array_of_functions[index++]('a string'); 

}


<button onclick="canvasp()">Next</button>
```

here in this code i have created a array containing two functions and increment the array onclick..on clicking the button the first function executes and if clicked again the second function executes but still the op of first function remains..i need only one function to execute on click and increment to second hiding the first..i tried of using for loop but not working can anybody help

chk this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/karthikchandran/hrvs4fzd/1/

Comment: The title of your question and its content don't match up. There's a big difference between asking how to loop through functions, and how to have a subsequent click ***undo*** the effect of the previous function before doing its thing.

Comment: sorry thanks for correcting..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a subsequent click to *undo* the effect of the previous function, you need a function that knows how to do that. The simplest thing is to include that in your array (which you should move *outside* the `canvasp` function, btw):

```
var index=0;
var array_of_functions = [
    canvaspoint,
    function(str) {
        undoCanvasPoint(str/* if needed */);
        canvaspoint1(str);
   }
];

function canvasp() { 

    if (index < array_of_functions.length) {
        array_of_functions[index++]('a string');
    }
}
```

A more complex solution would have an array of objects with `do` and `undo` properties, and use pre-increment instead of post-increment:

```
var index=-1;
var array_of_functions = [
    {
        "do": canvaspoint,
        "undo": undoCanvaspoint
    },
    {
        "do": canvaspoint1,
        "undo": undoCanvaspoint1
   }
];

function canvasp() { 
    if (index >= 0) {
        array_of_functions[index]["undo"]('a string if needed');
    }
    ++index;
    if (index < array_of_functions.length) {
        array_of_functions[index++]["do"]('a string');
    }
}
```

---

Side note: I'm putting `do` in quotes to be friendly to older JavaScript engines; current engines are in line with the current specification, which doesn't have a problem with keywords as property names provided they're unambiguously property names. (And then I do the same for `undo` just for consistency.)

Comment: thanks @T.J crowder ..i tried using your code but the undo is not working only the first function runs

Comment: @DeebanChakravarthi: There was an error around `index`, oddly enough I was just fixing it...

Comment: @DeebanChakravarthi: I fixed it above before commenting.

Comment: i tried now also its not working ..can u chk this fiddle what i have done wrong http://jsfiddle.net/karthikchandran/hrvs4fzd/2/

Comment: @DeebanChakravarthi: Well, for a start, you don't define the undo functions anywhere?!

Comment: i haven't defined undo functions @T.J crowder

Comment: @DeebanChakravarthi: Right. But you refer to them in your code. And so things break. I think you should probably step back from your current task and walk through some basic JavaScript/programming tutorials.

Comment: thanks @T.J crowder yes i will definitely do that..is there any way to solve this issue??

Comment: @DeebanChakravarthi: Define. Undo. Functions.